# Defining resValue conditionally in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am defining resValue in build.gradle like following

```
defaultConfig {
    ................................
    ................................ 
    resValue "string", "google_api_web_client_id", google_api_web_client_id

}
```

And the value is resided in `gradle.properties` file .

What I want is to put a separate value for debug build like, but the variable name should same `google_api_web_client_id`.

in my `gradle.properties` file  I have put the following

```
geo_api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
geo_api_key_debug=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

What I want is , when the build type is debug it will automatically take the debug value , in case of release it will take the release value . 
I can do it , by defining constant but in that case I have to put those value in build.gradle . Which I don't want .

How can I accomplish this ?

Comment: Have you tried giving it under `buildTypes {` in `android {`

Comment: Yes , but in that case I have to put the hardcoded value in `build.gradle`. I need to put those in `gradle.properties` file.

Comment: hey, did you find this answer correct - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56124826/9079028

Answer (score 2):

you can put it like this

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        resValue 'string', 'google_api_web_client_id', 'debug_key'
    }
    release {
        resValue 'string', 'google_api_web_client_id', 'release_key'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , but in that case I have to put debug_key or release_key in build.gradle file . Which I do not want to . I put those into gradle.properties .

Comment: Hey you can declare the variables in gradle.properties and use them directly in build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follow,

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "google_api_web_client_id", "YUOR_CLIEN_ID"
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "google_api_web_client_id", "YUOR_CLIEN_ID"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this help you and other with similar question

in your **`gradle.properties`**

```
MY_GOOGLE_API_KEY = "234235623"
```

in your **`build.gradle`** (app)

```
release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MY_GOOGLE_API_KEY')) {
                resValue 'string', MY_GOOGLE_API_KEY, 'release_key'
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Mithun if you find my answer correct, do care to mark it as accepted so it will be helpful to others